# How can I deploy a new Scrypto package to the Betanet using an API?

Tags: radix, scrypto, radix-dlt

I want to deploy a new version of my Scrypto package to the Betanet but I also want to avoid the manual work doing it through the dashboard.

Is there a way to do it through an API so I can automate this process easily?

I looked through the developer's documentation but could not find anything.